# It is possible to return to previous step while debugging with browser()

Tags: r

I wonder if there is a way to return to the previous step while debugging with the browser() function in R.

More Details: I am trying to debug a function to find when one of my variables becomes "NaN" inside of an loop.
So, in each iteration of this loop, I call a function "foo" to get the value of "X".
Currently, I hitting the "F10" (which is equivalent to input "n" in the console) until my variable  X becomes "NaN".

I problem is that I want to step back and get inside of the function "foo" just before X becomes a NaN in order to investigate what is going on there.

I know I could get inside of the function "foo" in each loop iteration, but this method it would be cumbersome.

It is possible to return to previous execution of the function "foo" ?

**EDIT**
To better explain what I need, here is an toy example of I want.

When I run the foo function, I receive some warnings about NaN.

The foo function is something like this one:

```
foo <- function(){
 X0 = 1
  for( i in 1:1000){
    X  <- foo.bar(X0)
    X0  <- X
  }
}
```

Sometimes, the foo.bar() function return NaN. My intention is to get inside of foo.bar() when this occurs to investigate the reasons of this undesirable results.

The problem is that I cannot know if foo.bar will return NaN before run the function.

Ps.: All routines inside of foo.bar is deterministic (ie, does not depend of random generated values).

Comment: You can only debug currently running code. You can't debug code that ran in the past so you can't "go back" to a previous state. You can move around in the current execution stack, but you can't recreate the past. You can trigger the debugger conditionally with the `browser()` command using the `expr=` parameter. Something like `for (i in 1:10) {browser(expr=i==4);print(i)}` will stop the program when `i==4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this in a fakery way.  Say you're about to execute line 100 but you want to "go back" to line 98.   First, manually revert any variables that were changed in line 98 or 99.  Depending on your code, you may be able to do simple things like  `foo <- 1:10` (where line 99 had done `foo<- foo + bar^2` , or perhaps , while still in the current debug level,  execute a previous block (e.g., lines 90:97) to rebuild the variables.  Then either copy/paste line 98 to execute again, or manually modify either variables or the command itself to change the outcome.

Comment: Thanks. This should work. I edit my question to add more details about my function. Could you explain to me with a little more details how I re-run the previous line of my code?

Comment: @RenatoFernandes  just copy from somewhere and paste into the console